# How commonly is the expression "jusqu’à temps/tant que" used?

Tags: expressions, usage

My friend just said to me jokingly:

> Alors si tu pouvais faire profil bas **jusqu’à temps que** tout soit réglé, s’il te plaît ?

This was the first time I'd heard of this expression, and given the context, I interpreted it on the spot as a synonym of "jusqu'à ce que". The word "temps" clued me in on it, I guess.

Then I went on to look it up in dictionaries, only to find that the correct phrasing was:

> Alors si tu pouvais faire profil bas **jusqu’à tant que** tout soit réglé, s’il te plaît ?

... not to mention the fact that "jusqu’à tant que" is supposedly only used in certain regions and "jusqu’à temps que" is considered nothing but a common spelling mistake taking root. As such, I'm not sure if I should include them into my active vocabulary.

Comment: Do you have an idea where your friend comes from ? I have never heard it, but I have just read this expression has an "archaic or regional usage".

Comment: @Greg Hi. She lived in a town near Mont Saint-Michel, but I haven't heard where she's *originally* from.

Comment: I for one use this expression, and always thought of it as *“jusqu'à temps que”*. I would not even know how to understand the alternate version, and would never use it, since I wouldn't know what I'd be saying *(though, obviously, people wouldn't know about this since they are pronounced the exact same way)*. Worth some investigation for sure... I'll see what people propose and what I can come up with.

Comment: La *Banque de dépannage linguistique* declares that it belongs primarily to the oral language, and that it should be [*jusqu'à tant que*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4320). I'll try and see what people have to say when they actually discuss the other version, which was left out altogether from that discussion.

Comment: @Feelew I just called her, and as it turned out, she's originally from Canada! You, too, right?

Comment: Yes indeed, I'm from Canada.

Comment: I come from north of France and it seems very familiar to me. I probably use it (but I am not so sure). And now I realize this is a weird phrase.

Comment: I live in the east of France (Alsace) and I never heard this expression. I use _jusqu'à ce que_ but it is probably as @Feelew said, the expression is specific to certain regions.

Comment: It is very common in casual spoken French in Marseille. Not sure if we can still qualify it as a regionalism when so much different areas use the expression.

Comment: @jlliagre Do you mean both "tant" and "temps" is quite common in your region?

Comment: *Tant* and *temps* are indistinguishable is spoken French but I always assumed it was *tant*. I would expect *temps* only in ***juste** à temps*.

Comment: Coming from North of France, I know the expression, but never actually said or heard it; but I read it a few times in books. Not the most common, people prefer "jusqu'à ce que".

Answer (score 2):

La *banque de dépannage linguistique* [déclare par défaut](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4320) que l’expression ***jusqu’à tant que*** est la seule option, ne mentionnant pas même ***jusqu’à temps que***, bien que l’on y précise aussi que l’expression *« peut [...] être utilisée pour exprimer une limite de **temps** »*. On y mentionne aussi l’emploi plutôt oral et familier, proposant d’y substituer « ***jusqu’à ce que*** » en langue soutenue.

---

Selon [*Le bon usage*](http://www.lebonusage.com/) (*§1136 <sup>a</sup>* pour la 14<sup>e</sup> édition, sinon cherchez ***jusque*** à l’index) :

> ***Jusqu'à tant que*** est archaïque ou régional (cf. Rézeau : dans le Nord, dans l’Ouest, en Auvergne, dans la région marseillaise ; en Wallonie ; en Amérique francophone)

- En tant que Québécois, je puis confirmer la vitalité de l’expression dans mon milieu d’origine *([Circeus](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/926) semble aussi le croire, si l’on se fie à son commentaire ci-dessous).*
- [jllagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/1109) a aussi confirmé que cette expression est commune dans la région marseillaise, et se dit d’avis que la tournure est plus que régionale, puisque présente dans tant de régions éparpillées un peu partout dans la Francophonie.
      <sub>→ Un point **pour** l’inclusion dans le vocabulaire usuel d’un francophile.</sub>
- [Distic](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/14487), du Nord de la France, a l’impression de connaître et même d’utiliser cette expression.
- D’autres gens de France (du Nord à nouveau et de l’Alsace), par contre, ont mentionné en commentaire sous la question ne l’avoir jamais entendue, ou très peu. Peut-être la trouverait-elle un peu disgracieuse s’il l’entendaient? Difficile à dire de la part de quelqu’un qui a toujours connu cette expression. Il serait intéressant de connaître ce qu’en disent les Auvergnats et les Belges, dont Rézeau dit qu’ils utilisent aussi cette tournure.
      <sub>→ Un point **contre** l’inclusion dans le vocabulaire usuel d’un francophile.</sub>
- Nous avons donc ici un bilan neutre quant à la décision pour un francophile d’incorporer ou non cette tournure dans son bagage linguistique français. Peut-être, si vous la jugez utile, pouvez-vous l’utiliser, quitte à la mettre de côté si elle est régulièrement mal reçue.

Si l’on revient au *Bon usage*, après l’introduction citée ci-dessus suivent quelques citations, dont :

> Et il commença à pratiquer son célèbre système de torsion de l’index ***jusqu’à tant que*** je ne croie plus au Père Noël. —DANINOS in *Sonia, les autres et moi*

Il est ensuite mentionné que :

> Quelques-uns écrivent, abusivement, ***jusqu’à temps que***.

On notera cependant que parmi ces quelques-uns se trouve un certain [Henry de Montherlant](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_de_Montherlant), académicien français, qui écrivit en 1924 dans son essai *Les Olympiques* :

> Laissez-moi vous regarder sans parole, ***jusqu’à temps que*** mon front s’abaisse.

---

<sub>Ainsi que je l’ai dit en commentaire sous la question, je n’ai personnellement utilisé dans ma vie que **jusqu’à temps que**, et mon esprit n’avait jamais conçu que l’on puisse signifier **jusqu’à tant que** par ces mêmes sons. Il semblerait que je fasse partie d’une minorité qui détourne l’expression, et quoique l’on retrouvât dans mon cas au moins un académicien français, il ne semble pas ici convenable que j’utilise outrageusement cette tribune pour mousser mon usage personnel. Je réduis donc la taille de cette section du texte afin de la marginaliser, ainsi que cela convient pour une tournure controversée.</sub>

---

***Comparaison avec « tant que »***

Je présente ici la raison pour laquelle je ne comprends pas *« jusqu’à tant que »*. Je serai heureux d’être démenti ou éclairé, si quelqu’un veut s’en donner la peine.

L’expression ***« tant que »*** est utilisée pour spécifier que jusqu’à ce qu’une certaine condition spécifiée ne soit plus valide, on pourra s’attendre à un certain état des faits :

> ***Tant qu***’il y aura des fruits, il y aura de l’alcool. —Richard Desjardins in *Kooloo Kooloo*

*« Tant que »* implique donc habituellement une plage temporelle, bornée par deux moments précis *(le présent de la narration et celui, subséquent, où la condition spécifiée ne sera plus vérifiée)*.

Si on adjoint *« jusqu'à »* à cette expression, pour obtenir *« jusqu’à tant que »*, nous avons un terme qui indique *(ici)* une **limite** temporelle *(jusque)* joint à une expression qui indique une **plage** temporelle *(tant que)*, ce qui est un peu comme si je disais *« Je travaille **jusque pendant** une heure »*, tournure absolument inhabituelle et grossièrement incorrecte.

Comment: *Jusqu'à tant que* est d'un usage [extrêmement commun au Québec](https://www.google.ca/search?q=site%3Alapresse.ca+"jusqu'à+tant+que") , d'où sa présence dans la BDL, qui s’intéresse surtout (et sans surprises!) à l'usage québécois.Pour référence, la section pertinente dans Le Bon usage (du moins mon édition, la 14e de 2008), et §1136 a).

Comment: @Circeus Il semble que la majorité des exemples trouvés par Google dans votre lien sont des citations de déclarations, non de la prose journalistique. Nous sommes donc en effet principalement dans la langue orale.

Comment: @Feelew Hum, ça ne fait pas partie du miens non plus... J'ai probablement confondu '-' Merci de la remarque!

Answer (score 0):

> Jusqu'à tant que est un vieux tour – né du croisement, faut-il le préciser, de jusqu'à et de tant que

comme indiqué [ici](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/jusqu-a-temps-que-a93789879).